# Equivalence relation in join of two spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let I be the unit interval. The join $X*Y$ is defined as
$$(X\times Y\times I)/\sim\,\,\mbox{with }\,\,I = [0; 1]$$
and the relation is given by $(x,y,0)\sim (x′,y,0), (x,y,1)\sim (x,y′,1)$ for $x\in X, y\in Y$.

I don't understand $\sim$ relation, i.e, $$\forall (x; y; t),\,\,(x'; y'; t')\in X\times Y\times I,\,\, (x; y; t) \sim (x'; y'; t') \leftrightarrow ??$$

Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't be so generous with tags, "metric-spaces" and "homological-algebra" are not relevant here...

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back to the intuitive idea of the join.

Suppose $X,Y$ are two subsets of Euclidean space of sufficiently high dimensions that the line segments joining points $x \in X$ to points $y \in Y$ do not meet. The union of these line segments is then the **join**  $X * Y$. Its points are $rx + sy$ where $r,s\geqslant 0$, and $r+s=1$. Here are some pictures 
 [image: joins]

$$\text{Fig.5.5}$$

taken from [Topology and Groupoids: pdf](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgrpds-e.pdf), Section 5.7.

Of course  we do not want to use generally an embedding in Euclidean space, so we define $X*Y$ to consist of "formal points" $rx + sy$ with $r,s$ as above except that if $r=0$ we ignore $rx$, getting just $y,$ and if $s=0$ we ignore $sy$, getting just $x$. A useful  topology on $X*Y$ is then an **initial topology**  as detailed in that Section, and which  I won't labour on here. This topology makes the join associative.

However a more commonly used topology is a **final topology** as an identification space of $X \times Y \times [0,1]$.

The initial topology is good for deciding continuity of maps into the join, while the final topology is good for deciding continuity of maps out of the join.

Comment: @ Ronnie Brown. Thank you very much! I want to ask if $X$ and $Y$ be two spaces, $A$ a subset of $Y$ , and $f: A\to Y$  a continuous map. then the quotient space  $$ X \bigcup\limits_{f}Y:= (X\bigsqcup Y)/[a \sim f(a),\,\,\forall a\in A]$$ 
is called the result of attaching or gluing the space Y to the space X via f. The map $f$ is the attaching map.

$X\bigsqcup Y$ space defined by $$X\bigsqcup Y = \{(x; X)\,\,|\,\,x\in X\} \bigcup \{(y; Y)\,\,|\,\,y\in Y\}.$$

Comment: $$\begin{array}{lll}
X \bigcup\limits_{f}Y&:=& (X\bigsqcup Y)/\sim = (X\times \{X\}\bigcup Y\times \{Y\})/\sim\\
&=& (X\times \{X\}\bigcup Y\times \{Y\})/(A\times \{X\}\bigcup f(A)\times \{Y\}),
\end{array}$$
 I understand this $\sim$ relation the following::$\forall  (u, W), (v, Z)\in X\bigsqcup ,Y $ then
$$(u, W)\sim (v, Z) \leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{l}
(u, W) =(v, Z),\\
u \in A,\,\,v = f(u),\,\,W = X,\,\,Z = Y,\\
v \in A,\,\,u = f(v),\,\,Z = X,\,\,W = Y,\\
u, v\in A,\,\,W = Z = X,\,\,f(u) = f(v),\\
u, v\in f(A),\,\,W = Z = Y.??
\end{array}\right.$$  right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The relation says $(x, y, t) \sim (x', y', t')$ if and only if either 1) $y = y'$ and $t = t' = 0$ or 2) $x = x'$ and $t = t' = 1$

Comment: @ manthanomen. I want ask If $G$ is a group and denote $E_n (G) := G ∗ G $ (join of $G$ and $G$) then why  a typical point in $E_n (G)$ is written as $$ t_1g_1 +t_2g_2,\,\,t_i\geqslant 0,\,\,g_i\in G,\,\,t_1  + t_2  = 1$$ Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!